# Python Discrete Fourier Transform with fftpack.fft: frequencies are not zero. Why?

Tags: python, fft

I perform a discrete Fourier transform on the sum of two sine waves using the following code:

```
def signal_samples(t):
    A1 = 4  #amplitude
    f1 = 1  #frequency [Hz]
    p1 = 0  #phase [rad]
    
    A2 = 2  #amplitude
    f2 = 22 #frequency [Hz]
    p2 = 0  #phase [rad]
    
    # sum of two sine waves        
    signal = (A1 * np.sin(2*np.pi*f1*t + p1) + A2 * np.sin(2*np.pi*f2*t + p2)) 
    
    return(signal)

B = 30                      #max frequency
f_s = 2*B                   #sampling frequency twice as high
delta_f = 0.01              #frequency resolution in spectrum
N = int(f_s / delta_f)      #number of samples
T = N / f_s 

t = np.linspace(0,T,N,endpoint=False)
s = signal_samples(t)

fig,axs = plt.subplots(1,2,figsize=(8,3),sharey=True)
axs[0].plot(t,s)
axs[0].set_xlabel("time (s)")
axs[0].set_ylabel("signal")
axs[1].plot(t,s)
axs[1].set_xlim(0,5)
axs[1].set_xlabel("time (s)")
plt.show()

# Perform Discrete Fourier Transform
F = fftpack.fft(s)               # FFT
f = fftpack.fftfreq(N,1.0/f_s)   # Get frequency bins to match FFT  

mask = np.where(f>=0) # spectrum is symmetric around 0; only take positive frequencies

fig, axs = plt.subplots(3,1,figsize=(8,6))
axs[0].plot(f[mask],np.log(abs(F[mask])), label="real")
axs[0].plot(B,0,'r*', markersize=10)
axs[0].set_ylabel("log |F|", fontsize=14)

axs[1].plot(f[mask],np.abs(F[mask])/N, label="real")
axs[1].set_ylabel("|F| / N", fontsize=14)
axs[2].plot(f[mask],np.abs(F[mask])/N, label="real")

axs[2].set_xlim(21,23)
axs[2].set_xlabel("Frequency (Hz)", fontsize=14)
axs[2].set_ylabel("|F| / N", fontsize=14)
plt.show()
```

The result is:

[image: result]

In the plot of log |F|, I see that most frequencies are not zero, but extremely small. Are these rounding errors of the algorithm? Or should I be worried?

Comment: The difference between your peak amplitude to those other extremely small amplitudes is over 30 in log scale. In terms of Decibels that's over 600dB. In comparison [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decibel) indicates that "The ratio of the sound intensity that causes permanent damage during short exposure to that of the quietest sound that the ear can hear is equal to or greater than 1 trillion (10^12) [...] which is expressed as a sound pressure level of 120 dB re 20 μPa." Unless you have an ultra-high accuracy application, I think that level of rounding errors should be OK.